# Handling null DB value with @Enumerated

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm having an enum like this:

```
public enum OverallResult {
    ACCEPT,
    REJECT,
}
```

and a POJO class like:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "OVERALL_RESULT", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private OverallResult overallResult;
```

So the issue is that I'm getting

```
Unknown name value for enum class ******.OverallResult:
```

Looks like it's having an issue with NULL values in the DB.

Any idea how to resolve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: why not post the exception + stack trace? The JPA provider I use (not Hibernate) has no problems with enum fields that are null ... you don't need to do anything to "handle" it.

Comment: Also, it would be great to see the content of the `pom.xml` file.

Comment: "Looks like it's having an issue with NULL values in the DB". Find out the exact query that is done when the problem occurs. You can configure hibernate to output all queries. Try to execute the same query directly on the database to see what is returned.

Comment: I see that the field is not insertable and not updatable. So your application is not putting any data in it.  Does the column in the database have a default value or are there values inserted manually or by another program? A typing error in such value resulting in an invalid value could be the cause of your problem.